# Install4J build fails with exceptions

Tags: java, install4j

I have following trial version of install4j Multi-Platform Edition 10.0.2 (build 10046) installed. Also installed are JDK 17.0.4 and JDK 1.8.333 (64 bit). I am getting following exceptions whenever I try to build:

```
Preparing configuration

Creating directory for temporary files

Directory for temporary media files is C:\Users\RAMCHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\install4j10000746811088592861_dir
Finding JDK release 8/latest [windows-amd64]

Build failed.

Cause: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
       timeout (loc: 4)
Stack trace:

com.exe4j.a.d: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout (loc: 4)
    at com.install4j.b.j.b(ejt:287)
    at com.install4j.gui.b.run(ejt:103)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout (loc: 4)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.win32.wininet.CallImpl.checkExceptionAndClose(CallImpl.java:60)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.win32.wininet.CallImpl.sendRequest(CallImpl.java:118)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.platform.win32.wininet.WinInet.open(WinInet.java:150)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.WinInetCallWrapper.connect(WinInetCallWrapper.java:57)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.HttpRequestHandler.createWindowsConnection(HttpRequestHandler.java:154)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.HttpRequestHandler.connect(HttpRequestHandler.java:129)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.TextRequestHandler.connect(TextRequestHandler.java:99)
    at com.install4j.jdk.spi.impl.a.a(ejt:123)
    at com.install4j.jdk.spi.impl.AdoptOpenJdkProvider.a(ejt:37)
    at com.install4j.jdk.spi.impl.a.a(ejt:120)
    at com.install4j.jdk.spi.impl.AdoptOpenJdkProvider.a(ejt:53)
    at com.install4j.jdk.spi.impl.AdoptOpenJdkProvider.a(ejt:14)
    at com.install4j.jdk.spi.impl.AdoptOpenJdkProvider$a$1$1.invokeSuspend(ejt:19)
    at com.install4j.jdk.spi.impl.AdoptOpenJdkProvider$a$1$1.a(ejt)
    at com.install4j.jdk.spi.impl.AdoptOpenJdkProvider$a$1$1.invoke(ejt)
    at com.install4j.jdk.spi.impl.a$a$a.invokeSuspend(ejt:134)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:749)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout (loc: 4)
        ... 24 more
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout (loc: 4)
        ... 24 more
    Suppressed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout (loc: 4)
        ... 24 more
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Seems like install4j is trying to run some HTTP request. We do not know why it is running the request, we do not know the URL it is trying to access, and we do not know your environment. Maybe you can figure out more information by using strace.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have internet connectivity, which is a problem for a build, because code signing and JRE bundle creation require an internet connection.

install4j will try to download a suitable JDK for script compilation. If you update to the current version (10.0.4+), there will be no failure in this case, just a warning that install4j will have to use the JRE that it is running with for that purpose.